# PGS subtitle track is out of sync after extracting then adding to another video file

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the Japanese and English version of a show. I am attempting to extract the subtitles and audio from the English version and add them to the Japanese version.

The video in both files seems to be exactly the same.

Here is the info for the streams contained in the english file. When playing this source video file `Track 2` subtitles seem to be almost empty while `Track 1` contains all of them forced.

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: dts (DTS-HD MA), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32p (24 bit) (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
      BPS-eng         : 1572054
      DURATION-eng    : 00:29:08.789333333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 163949
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 343648948
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.17.2 darwin(arm64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-12-18 02:20:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: dts (DTS), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Stereo
      BPS-eng         : 1509000
      DURATION-eng    : 00:29:08.789333333
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 163949
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 329865388
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001100
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.17.2 darwin(arm64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-12-18 02:20:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:3(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 22140
      DURATION-eng    : 00:28:47.454895833
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 836
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 4780741
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001200
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.17.2 darwin(arm64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-12-18 02:20:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
  Stream #0:4(eng): Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle
    Metadata:
      BPS-eng         : 1770
      DURATION-eng    : 00:28:39.655437500
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 62
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 380532
      SOURCE_ID-eng   : 001201
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: MakeMKV v1.17.2 darwin(arm64-release)
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2022-12-18 02:20:00
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES SOURCE_ID
```

I extract the english audio

```
ffmpeg -i s01e01_ja.mkv \
-muxdelay 0 \
-map 0:1 \
-vn \
-acodec copy \
s01e01_en_audio.dts
```

I extract the english subtitles

```
ffmpeg -i s01e01_en.mkv \
-muxdelay 0 \
-map 0:3 \
-vn \
-c copy \
s01e01_en_sub.sup
```

I add the english audio track to the japanese video

```
ffmpeg -i s01e01_ja.mkv \
-i s01e01_en_audio.dts \
-muxdelay 0 \
-map 0 \
-map 1:a \
-c copy \
-shortest \
s01e01_en_ja.mkv
```

And finally add the english subtitles to the new japanese video that contains english audio

```
ffmpeg -i s01e01_en_ja.mkv \
-itsoffset 6 \
-i future_boy_conan_s01e01_en_sub.sup \
-muxdelay 0 \
-map 0 \
-map 1:s \
-c copy \
-shortest \
s01e01_en_ja_subs.mkv
```

As you can see I need to offset the subtitles by 6 seconds in order to get the subtitles to sync with the audio. The english audio is in sync with the video.

I do not know how to debug this in order to tell if the subtitles are extracted or injected incorrectly causing the time offset. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ripping out subtitles to sup loses timing information. By doing this all in one shot it is all retained and solves this problem. I did have another issue while muxing (`Starting new cluster due to timestamp`) which I solved by adding the `-max_interleave_delta 0` flag. Here is my final solution.

```
ffmpeg -i s01e01_ja.mkv \
-i s01e01_en.mkv \
-max_interleave_delta 0 \
-muxdelay 0 \
-map 0 \
-map 1:a \
-map 1:s:0 \
-c copy \
s01e01_en_jp_subs_oneshot.mkv
```